# How can remove the line crossing the vertical resistor in this diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I recently started using CircuitTikZ and tried to make an electrical circuit. However, the resistor that connects both the upper line with the middle line, is crossed by a line inside itself.
Does anyone know how I can delete it?

[image]

```
\begin{circuitikz}[american] \draw
      (0,0) -- (0,8)
      (8,0) -- (8,8)
      to[resistor, l=$R$] (4,8) 
      to[resistor, l=$R_1$] (0,8)
      (1,8) -- (1,5) 
      (7,8) -- (7,5)
      to[resistor, l=$R$] (1,5) 


      (1,8) -- (1,11) 
      (7,8) -- (7,11)
      to[resistor, l=$R$] (4,11) 
      to[resistor, l=$R$] (1,11)

      (4,8) -- (4,11)
      to[resistor=$R$, i=$i_1$] (4,8)


      (1,0) -- (0,0)
      to[resistor, l=$R$] (8,0)
      (1,0) -- (1,-4)
      to[battery1, l=$V$] (7,-4) -- (7,0)
    ;
\end{circuitikz}
```

Comment: Welcome! Just remove `(4,8) -- ` in `(4,8) -- (4,11)`.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  (4,8) -- (4,11)
  to[resistor=$R$, i=$i_1$] (4,8)
```

draws a straight line from `(4,8)` to `(4,11)` and then adds a resistor on the path from `(4,11)` to `(4,8)`, i.e. on the same line run backwards. You say you do not want the straight line, so drop `(4,8) --`.

[image]